# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'd like to click the button 'Annual' at a page that is by default set on 'Quarterly'. There are two links that are basically called the same, except that one has `data-ptype="Annual"` so I tryed to copy the xpath to click the button (also tried other options but none did work).

However, I get the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`. I read a lot of similar posts, but wasn't able to fix my problem.. so I assume that javascript event must be called/clicked/performed somehow differnt.. idk Im stuck

```
from selenium import webdriver
link = 'https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-balance-sheet'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(link)
elm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]").click()
```

The html is the following:

```
<a class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray" href="javascript:void(0);" data-type="rf-type-button" data-ptype="Annual" data-pid="6408" data-rtype="BAL">..</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still suggest you to go with **linkText** over **XPATH**. Reason this xpath : `/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]` is quite absolute and can be failed if there is **one more div** **added** or **removed from HTML**. Whereas chances of changing the link Text is very minimal.

So, Instead of this **code** :

```
elm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]").click()
```

try this code :

```
annual_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Annual')
annual_link.click()
```

and yes @Druta is right, use `find_element` for one web element and `find_elements` for list of web element. and it is always good to have `explicit wait`.

Create instance of explicit wait like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
```

and use the wait reference like this :

```
wait.until(EC.elementToBeClickable(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Annual'))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
link = 'https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-balance-sheet'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)
driver.get(link)  

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)") 

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Annual')))
annual_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Annual')
annual_link.click()
print(annual_link.text)
```

make sure to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: @Felix : I have updated my answer under update section. This code works fine on my machine. You will have to scroll down to interact with Annual button. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

you need to use `find_element_by_xpath` not `find_elements_by_xpath` that return a `list`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]").click()
```

Also i think is better to use [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for example.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)

path = "/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]"
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                           EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, path)))
    element.click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: A thanks, but I still get an error cause a popup shows up.. Is there a way around it?  Cause I get: ElementClickInterceptedException: 'Element <a class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray" href="javascript:void(0);"> is not clickable at point (175.29999542236328,530.3166961669922) because another element <div class="consentBarWrapper"> obscures it'

Comment: i update my answer, try to add `options` to open `firefox` on full window, but i run the code without `options` and it works

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation [find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) returns a *List* with elements if any was found or else an empty list if not. Python's *List* have no *click()* method associated with it. Instead  [find_element_by_xpath(xpath)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) method have the *click()* method associated with it. So you have to use `find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` method inducing a *waiter* through [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) set as  [element_to_be_clickable(locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='newBtn toggleButton LightGray' and @data-type='rf-type-button']"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `find_elements_by_xpath` is *plural* it returns a *list* of elements. Not just one. The list can contain none, exactly one, or more elements.

You can for example click the first match with:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]")[0].click()
```

or iterate through the list and click all these elements, or you can use the `find_element_by_xpath` (which returns a single element, if it can be found):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/section/div[8]/div[1]/a[1]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was not working, and tried a hell lot of tricks, and none worked. Some people recommended driver.implicitly_wait(10) instead of time.sleep(10) which didn't work. so please try giving time.sleep(10) both above and below the .click() code line, and check if it works or not.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer